# How to download a pdf at adonis 5

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

Hi Everybody im using adonis 5 in my backend and im saving files at public directory i can to see and to download images but this does not working in pdf file, this working at adonis js 4.1 using adonis drive but drive its not in Adonis 5 there is a some way for to see or to download pdf ad adonis 5?

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1:**

If you just want to send back a **file URL** to let your users decide whether to download it or not, you can simply put that file in your `public` folder and send them the link: e.g. `http://{{YOUR_HOST}}/filename.ext`

This will work just fine until you have the static server [configured properly](https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/http/static-files#setup).

**Case 2:**

If you want to forcibly make users download your files - rather than just visiting them in the browser - you may want to use the `attachment` helper which automatically sets proper response headers for downloading files.

`ctx.response.attachment('public/filename.ext')`